# S-Shaped/Vertical ROC curve crossing the diagonal

Tags: logistic, roc, sensitivity-specificity

I am running binary logistic regression and when the ROC curve is created this is the output (see below):

I believe it makes sense somewhat, as the model does have 100% specificity and 0% sensitivity at the moment, but what consequences does it have? Is it okay to continue with the analysis? Is it just a mistake made in graphing the ROC curve? The other tests indicate the model is good and useful but I am not sure how to interpret the ROC graph in this case.

Thank you in advance :)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain why you have initially a decreasing specificity without an improvement of sensitivity? For instance, at some point you have 75% specificity, which means that of the true negatives 25% get a false positive result, while among the true positives there is 0 sensitivity and 0% get a positive result. Why does your classification give a positive for some true negatives but not at all for some true positives?

Comment: An explanation could be that the positive group has a smaller variation than the negative group, and that your decision should not be based on a single boundary but on two boundaries. For instance, if the true positives have value 0.5 and the true negatives a uniform distributed between 0 and 1, then a decision rule positive if value above x will give the pattern as in your graph and with X=0.49 you will have 100% sensitivity but bad specificity (because you also falsely detect 51% of the true negative group as positive). A better decision would be 'positive if value between 0.49 and 0.51.

Comment: Did you make this graph using the predicted *probabilities*, or did you perhaps round the probabilities to be either 0 or 1? Or something else?